# SR Suntour Fork Disassembly - No Screw/Bolt near Dropouts / Giant Sedona LX 2005

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, suspension

I have a Giant Sedona LX... probably from 2005 (?) with an SR Suntour fork on it. Magnesium...

**I'm trying to disassemble the fork to inspect whether it is rusted (and will be tossed as it is not worth the effort) or needs a rebuild.**

I can't find the model because it's too old. I looked on bikepedia and elsewhere, using the serial number and the bike model.

I'm trying to take the outer arms off but there is no hex bolt/screw anywhere near the dropouts. It's just circular.

Any help? I'm missing something really obvious? Thanks.

[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 2]

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Kegan. At this stage I don't see the images.

Comment: Thanks @andy256, Unsure what I did incorrectly... I do see them fine and tested on another computer. I made an edit... I hope it helps!

Comment: Images visible now.

Comment: Are you trying to disassemble the fork? Are you trying to remove the "lower legs" the painted part of the fork?

Comment: @mikes Yes, I'm trying to disassemble the fork. Sorry, used to calling them outer legs (which became arms) or sliders. The ones I've seen have all had a screw or hex bolt somewhere around the dropouts. No luck there. Could I come down from the preload knobs?...

Comment: I don't think it was designed to be disassembled. Maybe try vice grips? What can you see if you shine a light inside the circular part?

Comment: Just another round, metal tube within that does not completely touch the walls. Very small gap between the 'barrel' of the circular part and the inside part. Can't be moved with an allen key of similar size, up or down, left or right.